# Forwarding Blazor RenderFragment parameter to child components throws exception

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor

Update: this issue is acknowledged by Microsoft. ([Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/23892)), and will be likely fixed/resolved in .Net 6 ([github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/32288)).

---

I can use a RenderFragment to pass (child) content to a component. And that can be optional. Take:

```cs
@*Baz.razor*@
@if (Bar is null)
{
    <div>nobar</div>
}
else
{
    <div>Render bar: @Bar</div>
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment Bar { get; set; }
}
```

I can do

```cs
@*FooPage.razor*@
@page "/foopage"
<Baz />
```

which renders "nobar", or

```cs
@*FooPage.razor*@
@page "/foopage"
<Baz Bar=@bar/>

@code {
    private RenderFragment bar = (builder) => { builder.AddMarkupContent(0, "<div>bar</div>"); };
}
```

which renders "Render bar: bar" (with a newline due to the div)

So, now I have a new situation where there's a component in-between the two, called `Foo`.

```cs
@*Foo.razor*@
<Baz Bar=@Bar />

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment Bar { get; set; }
}
```

And I modify FooPage.razor to

```cs
@*FooPage.razor*@
@page "/foopage"
<Foo />
```

I.e. I'm forwarding the `Bar` parameter from `Foo` to `Baz`... this doesn't work and gives me a quite lengthy error (at the bottom of this question). (Note: it does work when I assign `Bar` in FooPage.)

This is very weird to me. I can check if `Bar` is null, and use it or not. However, I cannot explicitly set `Bar` to null, or pass a null reference.

I've also tried this directly by doing:

```
@*FooPage.razor*@
@page "/foopage"
<Foo Bar=@nullrf />

@code {
    private RenderFragment nullrf;
}
```

which also throws the same exception.

I.e. if you leave it out, it's null, bu if you assign it null it breaks. Is this a bug?

```
ArgumentException: Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'.
System.MulticastDelegate.ThrowNullThisInDelegateToInstance()
System.MulticastDelegate.CtorClosed(object target, IntPtr methodPtr)
BlazorServerDefault.Pages.Foo.BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder __builder)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.<.ctor>b__6_0(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderInExistingBatch(RenderQueueEntry renderQueueEntry)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.HandleException(Exception exception)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessPendingRender()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.AddToRenderQueue(int componentId, RenderFragment renderFragment)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.StateHasChanged()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallOnParametersSetAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.HandleException(Exception exception)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.AddToPendingTasks(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SetDirectParameters(ParameterView parameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderRootComponentAsync(int componentId, ParameterView initialParameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.CreateInitialRenderAsync(Type componentType, ParameterView initialParameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.RenderComponentAsync(Type componentType, ParameterView initialParameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext+<>c__11<TResult>+<<InvokeAsync>b__11_0>d.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.StaticComponentRenderer.PrerenderComponentAsync(ParameterView parameters, HttpContext httpContext, Type componentType)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ComponentRenderer.PrerenderedServerComponentAsync(HttpContext context, ServerComponentInvocationSequence invocationId, Type type, ParameterView parametersCollection)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ComponentRenderer.RenderComponentAsync(ViewContext viewContext, Type componentType, RenderMode renderMode, object parameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.ComponentTagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.<RunAsync>g__Awaited|0_0(Task task, TagHelperExecutionContext executionContext, int i, int count)
BlazorServerDefault.Pages.Pages__Host.<ExecuteAsync>b__14_1() in _Host.cshtml
+
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext.SetOutputContentAsync()
BlazorServerDefault.Pages.Pages__Host.ExecuteAsync() in _Host.cshtml
+
    Layout = null;
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: > This is very weird to me.

Not to me...

From my own experience, if you want to create a templated component with optional Footer template, you don't assign a null value to the parameter attribute, but instead, you skip adding it, and then you check if the parameter property is null or not. When you check whether the parameter property's value is null or not, you actually check the existence of a value, and not it's intrinsic value, whatever it may be.

Comment: @enet, yeah, but there doesnt seem to be a way to *conditionally* add a parameter. Based on some state, I want it either to be there or not. There are some more questions like this around on SO, no good answers though.

Comment: And still no way to forward parameters. Note, in a real life situation there are many parameters, so making conditional statements for each will grow O(N!).

Comment: The real question that should be asked is why do you want to forward a null value's parameter. And it is the daily routine of a programmer to check for conditions. Do you make conditional statements before you trigger an event handler delegate ? That's the same. Again, why pass a delegate with a null value ? You can't do anything with it, so don't pass it.

Comment: @enet i don't *want* to pass a delegate with a null value. However, the designers of Blazor have chosen to implement a RenderFragment that way. What I want to do is to template child content and pass that content along. RenderFragment seems to be the way to go, I find on many pages.

Comment: @enet thinking about this more, in a different scenario, passing a null reference of *anything* shouldn't be a problem, as long as it is checked for null at the (final) site where it is actually used, which it is in this case. The problem with RenderFragment parameters in blazor is that a null check seems to be required on every step, with conditional implementions based on that. Furthermore, in my case it would conditionally be null.

Answer (score 2):

When you are attempting to pass `Bar` as an attribute, the Razor compiler will attempt to render it as part of the Foo component, which is not what you want and is why it fails when Bar is null.

You could achieve your goal - if the real use case suits this - by attribute splatting.

```html
@*Foo.razor*@
<Baz @attributes=PassThrough/>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment Bar { get; set; }
    Dictionary<string,object> PassThrough;
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        PassThrough = new Dictionary<string,object>();
        PassThrough.Add(nameof(Baz.Bar),this.Bar);
    }
}
```

Edit: Test here : [Blazor Repl](https://blazorrepl.com/repl/GlYmQCuF32Y95aTC49)

Comment: Thanks. I hope this is not the only/best solution. The example I gave was greatly simplified. In the real project we want to port (from forms) there would be a whole hierarchy of components, each having several sub-components. Having to keep track of all "pass-through" parameters for each component separately will make the code dirty and hard to maintain...

Comment: I think I already get confused by "When you are attempting to pass Bar as an attribute, the Razor compiler will attempt to render it as part of the Foo component"... first thing: it's not an attribute, it's a parameter right? "attribute" is a HTML thing. But Blazor components are C# classes under the hood. `Bar` is a property, which has the `ParameterAtrribute`. Sowwhen I say `<Baz Bar=@Bar />` I expect the compiler to generate `var barObj = new Baz { Bar=Bar };`. Why would it try to render it if you pass it? It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Ok, I'm not here to argue about attributes, it's a vague area - but the value of the parameter is set through an attribute in razor and in the rendertree. I am sure there are always other ways to do things, and you could absolutely call this a bug and log an issue as it would be easy to argue that a renderfragment being passed in this way should just pass through.

Comment: My own experience is this - once you start hitting problems like this, it's a fairly good sign that your design has issues - I'm not saying it definitely does, but it's a good time to take a step back and check - passing renderfragments straight through like this feels like a potential error in the design -  but I totally accept that I don't have enough detail about your project to know that for sure :)

Comment: Thanks. I'm currently in a big project, which is dated and a lot of spaghetti code. They use some kind of "form generator" project, which is fed enormous arrays of component (different kind then razor) templates. Those get converted to database entries, which needs to be regenerated for each update. It's very hard to maintain and easy to mess up. I'm trying to show my team we could replace it using Blazor/Razor Components, which will make life so much easier. But if we cannot have hierarchy, passing something like RenderFragments along, I will have a very hard time selling it...

Comment: ...completely rethinking the design will just cost too much time (and money) that there's no ROI.

Comment: The question is what is foo for?

Comment: `Foo` is a simplified version of such a "component". Could be a form (html kind), data entry field assembly (label+textbox+whatever), buttons/checkboxes/pulldowns/etc, sets of the prior, etc etc etc we're talking about 80,000 lines of template code! Anyhow. I already had a topic on this in the aspnet github and now I've stumbled on something very weird: If you build the render tree yourself, this issue doesn't occur: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/30534#issuecomment-787430089

Comment: That was going to be the next suggestion, glad you found it

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really the answer but I need somewhere to put some code that's better than a comment.

The issue lies in the way the razor code is pre-compiled into the `BuildRenderTree` method when building the proper class for the Razor Component. Blame the component builder.  You need to declare RenderFragments in the way Razor expects them.

Your coding - using the attribute approach:

```
<Baz Bar="@Bar"></Baz>
```

The Razor builder turns this into:

```
    public partial class Foo2 : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase
    {
        #pragma warning disable 1998
        protected override void BuildRenderTree(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder __builder)
        {
            __builder.OpenComponent<TestBlazorServer.Components.Bar>(0);
            __builder.AddAttribute(1, "Bar", 
#nullable restore
          Bar

#line default
#line hidden
#nullable disable
            );
            __builder.CloseComponent();
        }
        #pragma warning restore 1998
#nullable restore
#line 3        
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment Bar { get; set; }
```

Note that `Bar` is added as an attribute, as explained in the answer above.

Now if you declare it like this:

```
<Baz>
 <Bar>@Bar</Bar>
</Baz>
```

You get this where `Bar` gets added correctly as a RenderFragment.

```
    public partial class Foo : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase
    {
        #pragma warning disable 1998
        protected override void BuildRenderTree(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder __builder)
        {
            __builder.OpenComponent<TestBlazorServer.Components.Bar>(0);
            __builder.AddAttribute(1, "Baz", (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderFragment)((__builder2) => {
                __builder2.AddContent(2, 
#nullable restore
#line 5          
Bar

#line default
#line hidden
#nullable disable
                );
            }
            ));
            __builder.CloseComponent();
        }
        #pragma warning restore 1998
#nullable restore
#line 9        
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment Bar { get; set; }
```

This bit my rear end a few months ago building components in code.  Anyway, I'm not sure if you can build your stuff this way, but it explains what you see.

Comment: thanks! I'll check this `__builder.OpenComponent<TestBlazorServer.Components.Bar>(0);` Is this a typo? i.e. should it be `__builder.OpenComponent<TestBlazorServer.Components.Baz>(0);` (or even `Foo`?) There's no component `Bar`?

Comment: Also, the first code actually seems to work OK, [as I discovered](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/30534#issuecomment-787430089)

Comment: I have a component called Bar: typo in the component names when I was building the components in a test site!   I assume you know where to look for the razor generated code?

Comment: No, I do not and it doesn't seem that easy to find on google. Could you please point me to it (or some doc)?

Comment: Just explore in the project `obj` folder.    ..\SPA\obj\Debug\net5.0\Razor is the path to the razor build class files for my SPA project Library.  Each file is xxx.razor.g.cs.

Comment: Thanks! I found what's happening. Instead of generating `builder.AddAttribute(1, "Bar", Bar);`, its generating `builder.AddAttribute(1, "Bar", new RenderFragment(Bar));`. I.e. some sort of copy constructor that fails if the input is `null`.

Comment: NP. Glad to assist.  Being retired, I'm locked up in Lockdown!!!